# array data send by post method in node.js,how to print on console i tried this

Tags: javascript, node.js

detail:how to print a specific value only
on the console of the array which is send on server by post method

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var mj = new Array();
    mj = req.body.equip;
    console.log("this" + req.body.equip[]);
    console.log(mj);
});
```

i used this but it is not giving result

```
 <input type="text" name="equip[]">
 <input type="text" name="equip[]">
 <input type="text" name="equip[]">
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Pass data to the server and console.log it on the server?

Answer (score 2):

I think below code will help you to print each values.

```
var array=req.body.equip;
array.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element);
}, this);
```